# INNER JOIN таблиц по уникальным значениям поля одной из таблиц

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть две таблицы - t2 - лог действий клиентов, где ID клиента повторяется по несколько раз. Таблица t1 - статичная пользовательская информация о клиентах, где ID уникален.

Мне необходимо выбрать информацию из t1 по уникальным клиентам, которые фигурируют в t2.

В настоящий момент из базы выгружаю данные таким образом:

```
select CLIENT_DK, column2, column3, column4 from TABLE1.NAME t1
inner join TABLE2 t2 on t2.CLIENT_ID = t1.CLIENT_DK
```

Такой способ джойнит информацию о клиентах ко всем соответствующим записям из лога клиентских действий, что загромождает выгрузку. Можно ли сразу облегчить выгрузку, указав уникальность по CLIENT_ID сразу в запросе?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение на основе подзапроса:

```
select CLIENT_DK, column2, column3, column4 from TABLE1.NAME t1
inner join (select distinct CLIENT_ID from TABLE2) t2 on t2.CLIENT_ID = t1.CLIENT_DK
```

Подзапрос предобрабатывает таблицу логов так, чтобы там остались только уникальные ID клиентов.

Также работает решение ниже к комментариях

Comment: Такой запрос может работать даже дольше чем оригинал. Надо сравнивать планы выполнения... Ещё стоит попробовать вариант с where clieint_id in (select client_id in table2) и опять же сравнить план выполнения

Comment: Ваш запрос работает даже быстрее моего, спасибо. Оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ, я его отмечу

Comment: Я лучше воздержусь.... Хороший ответ должен влючать сравнение планов выполнения запросов, а для этого надо иметь доступ к этим двум таблицам и их метаданным - нужно знать все индексы и статистики, собранные Oracle об этих двух таблицах и их индексах. Без этих данных можно только гадать)